# Why i am getting this error? Enterprise Library 4.1.0.0 exception handling logging tracing

Tags: c#, vsto, enterprise-library

we are using Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1.0.0 i our application for logging and tracing. In one case, I am getting error as:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for exceptionHandling: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040). (C:\Program Files\Datastream\Datastream Charting Add-In\Office2007\Thomson.Reuters.Datastream.Charting.ICAddInCore.dll.config line 4)

Below is the ICAddInCore.dll.config 4th line:

```
<section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8ef321d56661a4cd" />
```

Kindly help?

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

The version of the DLL it is trying to load does not match the version in the config.

Comment: Clearly they are not, that is what the exception says, when i says version i mean that the fully qualified name is different.  The most likely explanation is that it is loading a different dll than you think it is.

Comment: can u plz tell how to determine the assembly's fully qualified name that is getting loaded and in the config?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PublicKeyToken is incorrect.  The Microsoft supplied Enterprise Library PublicKeyToken is 31bf3856ad364e35.

Are you building and signing Enterprise Library your self or are you using a different version of the configuration tool?  Or perhaps it's a copy and paste error?

If you are using out of the box Enterprise Library your config should be:

```
    <section name="exceptionHandling" 
      type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, 
      Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

If you think you really should be using `PublicKeyToken=8ef321d56661a4cd` then your project is probably referencing a Microsoft signed version of Enterprise Library so you should fix that reference.

Comment: When i loaded the current's project config files to Enterprise Library Configuration, I got some errors as in my question. When i changed the Public Token Key from 8ef321d56661a4cd to 31bf3856ad364e35 in the config files, I did not get any errors. The above error is coming when we try to export the chart from web and the clicked button caling the dll. How to fix the dlls references?

Comment: I have run sn -t command on the dll Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll. Got this message: 
Failed to convert key to token -- The public key for assembly '(null)' was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue is not exactly where the error message shows. I have encountered this error various times and I still don't know how I resolved it the last time. I think I did a clean build after restarting VS.